# OSX Mavericks as Virtual guest on Apple hardware running Windows 7, 8, etc

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, vmware-fusion

Is it possible / legal to install Windows on Apple Hardware (macbook), and run OSX as a Virtual Guest using vmware or virtualbox?

EDIT: 1/8/2014 --

I realize this question may not be as clear as it could be, and may be an unusual request for information.

- **HOST:** Apple Hardware (Macbook) running Windows 7, 8, etc
- **Virtual Guest:**  Mac OSX

Comment: Yes, and as proof MAC come with bootcamp which specifically is designed for running windows on your MAC virtually.

Comment: Bootcamp does not run Windows on Mac virtually. Bootcamp is a fancy name for dual boot.

Comment: @cybernard Besides the comment of Cocoaster, the question here is **running MAC virtual** under Windows (on Apple hardware). **Not** running Windows virtually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Legality**

Yes, it is legal (and even permitted in the EULA) to run OSX as a Virtual Guest using VMWare or VirtualBox. It doesn't matter if the host-OS is Windows or Mac OSX itself as long as it is on Apple-labeled hardware.

When looking at the [Software License Agreement for Mac OS X](http://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/MacOSX.htm) it clearly states:

> This License allows you to install and use one copy of the Apple
>   Software on a single Apple-labeled computer at a time.

(not sure if you need a *separate* licence if you follow that one :)

From another document from Apple: [SOFTWARE LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR OS X MOUNTAIN LION](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1082.pdf):

> B. Mac App Store License. If you obtained a license for the Apple Software from the Mac App Store
>   ...
>   (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or
>   instances of the Apple  Software within virtual operating system
>   environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already
>   running the Apple Software, for purposes of: (a) software 
>   development; (b) testing during software development; (c) using OS X
>   Server; or (d)  personal, non-commercial use

(No need for a *separate* licence if obtained via the Mac App Store:)

From [VMWare](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1000131):

> According to Apple's licensing policies, VMware only supports the
>   virtualization of Apple Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) client or
>   server, Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) client or server, 10.6 (Snow Leopard)
>   server and 10.5 (Leopard) server.
>
> The End User License Agreement (EULA) for Apple Mac OS X legally and
>   explicitly binds the installation and running of the operating system
>   to Apple-labeled computers only. Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard Server, 10.6
>   Snow Leopard Server, 10.7 Lion client or server and 10.8 Mountain Lion
>   client or server are fully supported on VMware Fusion while running on
>   supported Apple hardware.

Other sources:
http://www.instructables.com/answers/Is-it-legal-to-run-Mac-OS-X-in-Windows-on-Virtualb/
http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1802838/illegal-run-osx-virtual-box.html
https://discussions.apple.com/message/20159533#20159533
and lots more via... Google [legal mac os in virtualbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=legal+mac+os+in+virtualbox) and [legal mac os in virtualbox](https://www.google.com/search?q=legal+mac+os+in+vmware).

A final note on the legality. Even if something might be against the EULA that doesn't mean it is illegal. Check your local legislation. In many places in the world the OS X EULA is not legally binding or enforceable.

---

**Practicality**

When you create a VM in VirtualBox it even recognizes the OS when you're trying to install OSX (if using a VM-name as "Mac OS" or "OSx" or similar).

However there are no "Guest additions" available in VirtualBox for OSX (for optimizing speed, display, etc...) so you might want to try both VirtualBox and VMWare to see which runs your guest-OS the smoothest.

[image]